# Properties of a certain divisor of the $m^{\rm th}$ root of unity in the $m^{\rm th}$ cyclotomic ring.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I am an analyst who is new to algebraic number theory. I am learning on Cyclotomic polynomials and came across this problem, which I am having hard time solving.

Let $\xi$ be an $m^{\rm th}$ complex root of unity. For each prime divisor $p$ of $m$, let $\xi_p := {\xi_m}^{\frac{m}{p}}$. Let $$g = \Pi_{prime \space p | m}(1-\xi_p)$$

Let $Z$ denote the ring of integers. Show that $g\in Z[\xi_m]$, divides $m$ in $Z[\xi_m]$ if $m$ is odd and $\frac m2$ if $m$ is even. Furthermore, show that $g$ is co-prime with every integer prime except the odd prime divisors of $m$.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, first I think you might want to take $\zeta_m$ to be a primitive $m$th root of unity, as otherwise your product will be zero. Then $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity, and you have probably seen that $(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$ is a unit times $p$, and so $1-\zeta_p$ divides $p$.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @TokenToucan. I actually have not seen the fact you mentioned (I am super new to the subject). I'll try to prove it and see where that takes me.